# Problem with formula for parabolic motus

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile

I know that the path made by an object thrown in air with velocity $v_0$ with an angle $\alpha$ is:
$$y=x \cdot\tan \alpha - \frac {gx^2}{2v_0^2\cdot \cos^2 \alpha} $$

At school we had to use this formula for exercises and I decided to plot it on my computer using different angles like  $\alpha = 45$ and the graphic of that is: [image]

but when I out $\alpha = 30$:
[image]
Which doesn't make any sense because it's negative! I can't understand why is the graph is so different,
can somebody help me?

Answer (score 3):

I think your plotting routine is expecting angles in radians, not degrees.

The starting angle of both graphs is wrong.  The first is not $45^\circ$, and the second is nowhere near $30^\circ$.  $\tan(30)=-6.4$ (if $30$ is in  *radians*) and that would explain the negative start.

Also: did you square the cosine in the denominator?  The formulas above the graph do not show that the cosine is squared.